# Вывод ошибки подключения к базе данных или выполнения запроса

Tags: java, база-данных, sql, postgresql, linux

Есть код

```
    public void readUsingDataFromDatabase(ArrayList<String> therms, ArrayList<Integer> idOfFiles, ArrayList<Integer> countThermsInFiles, String url, String user, String password, int countFiles)
    {
        Connection con = null;
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;        
        String currentFile;
        int countThermsInFile; 
        try
        {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                    st = con.createStatement();
                    rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT a.value, c.value, c.id FROM therms a INNER JOIN therms_occurs b ON b.therm_id = a.id INNER JOIN fs_entries c ON b.file_id = c.id ORDER BY a.value, c.value, c.id");
            rs.first();
            therms.add(rs.getString(1));
            countThermsInFile=1; 
            currentFile=rs.getString(2); 
            idOfFiles.add(rs.getInt(3)); 
            countFiles=1; 
            while (rs.next()) 
            { 
                if (currentFile!=rs.getString(2)) 
                    {
                        countThermsInFiles.add(countThermsInFile); 
                        countFiles+=1; 
                        currentFile=rs.getString(2); 
                        countThermsInFile=1; 
                        idOfFiles.add(rs.getInt(3)); 
                    }
                else
                    {
                        countThermsInFile+=1; 
                    }; 
                therms.add(rs.getString(1));
            };
            countThermsInFiles.add(countThermsInFile); 
        }
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
```

Хочу уточнить - если к базе данных не удалось подключиться и что тоже не маловажно не выполнился запрос, то тогда сработают операторы после catch и мне будет выведена ошибка? Если же эти операторы не сработают, то подключение и запрос **точно** были выполнены удачно? (извините возможно глупый вопрос, но я лишь уточняю, посокльку это очень важно для меня).

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос действительно глупый. Точный ответ состоит в том, что `catch` перехватит любое исключение типа `SQLException` выброшенное внутри блока `try` :)

Конечно, это звучит как масло-масляное, но ответ именно таков.

В конкретном вашем случае выброс исключения `SQLException` необязательно произойдет только из-за ошибки подключения, есть миллион вариантов почему это произойдет :) И более того, при ошибке подключения вполне может быть выкинут другой миллион исключений, который вы не перехватываете.

Я бы посоветовал если вам уж непременно хочется в `catch` поймать любые вообразимые/невообразимые исключения, то сделать примерно так:

```
try {
   //blah-blah
}
catch(Throwable th) {
   System.out.println("Что-то пошло не так!");
   th.printStackTrace();
   return;
}
System.out.println("Ура все прошло удачно!");
```